# condition in timeout function not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, timeout

I have the following code where I am trying to increase the height of a div when hovering on it with your mouse. I wanted to set a timeout though to delay the closing when unhovering. To avoid the div closing when the mouse is back on it I created the mouseon state, it is adjusting accordingly but for some reason it seems like its not adjusting in the timeout function. Why?

```
function Component (props) {

    const [large, setLarge] = useState(false);
    const [mouseon, setMouseon] = useState()

    const handleMouseEnter = () => {
        document.getElementById(`medium`).style.height = '800px';
        setLarge(true);
        setMouseon(true)
    }

    const handleMouseLeave = () => {
        setMouseon(false);
        setTimeout(()=>{
            if(!mouseon){
                document.getElementById(`medium`).style.height = '0px';
                setLarge(false);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

return (<>
        
                <div id={`medium`}>
                    Something something text
                    {mouseon ? "mouseon" : 0}
                </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a CSS hover style and transition be better suited for this? You never clear the timeout, so if the user mouses over, then off, then back on, a timeout is still running. The timeout also isn't cleared when the component unmounts, which can throw a react error/warning about setting state of an unmounted component. Direct DOM manipulations are also generally considered an anti-pattern in react.

Comment: In React, MUST NOT deal with raw DOM by DOM API. If you want to, use `useRef` hook instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your mouseon state was'nt changed when you calling setTimeout. You can using useEffect to check if state mouseon is changed and call setTimeout.

```html
const handleMouseLeave = () => {
  setMouseon(false);
};

useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!mouseon) {
      document.getElementById(`medium`).style.height = "0px";
      setLarge(false);
    }
  }, 1000);
}, [mouseon]);
```